# Calling a store procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, jboss6.x

I am beginning a JTA UserTransaction, and calling a stored procedure in that transaction using another connection object.

At run time I am getting the following exception:

**This stored procedure must run outside a transaction! Number of currently open transactions: 1. This error will not cause a rollback of any open transactions.**

Is there a way to solve this problem. Can I suspend the JTA transaction and resume it after calling the stored procedure.